# Are there any buildings standing that Jesus visited?

Tags: life-of-jesus

I am wondering if there are any buildings that are still standing that Jesus visited. Thanks.

Comment: Lots of buildings people now visit in pilgrimages are claimed to be the homes of Peter, the others apostles, Mary and Martha etc, but whether you accept those claims is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site.  Things are a bit different here, so it's recommended to at least take the [tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how things work. You may also find this Meta post helpful: [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-that-are-within-community-guidelines?s=2|0.4060).

Answer (score 6):

Many smaller locations are often debated.

[Herodian architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herodian_architecture) is unique and identifiable, making it a good reference for what was around at the time of Jesus' birth. Unfortunately, only one Herodian building is still standing: The Enclosure of the [Cave of the Patriarchs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave_of_the_Patriarchs), Hebron.

The [Wailing Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wailing_wall) was also standing there in Jesus' day, but it is hardly a standing building.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for offering an answer here. For more about what this site is all about, please see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Answer (score 1):

The *Archaeological Study Bible* in my possession has many photos of places excavated where Jesus may have been near. Many are ruins, of course. Here is a short list.

- p312: Walls of Jericho.
- p1584: "Herod the Great's lavish palaces in Jerusalem, Masada and
  Jericho."
- p1591, 1643: "the synagogue of Capernaum."
- p1623: "Archaeological excavations conducted beneath the Church of
  the Annunciation have revealed that ancient Nazareth was an
  agricultuural village. Pottery was found ther dating from the Iron
  Age II (900-600 B.C....)"
- p1627: Herod's palace at Jericho has been excavated. The Herodium
  near Bethlehem was excavated.
- p1651: "Temple to Ceasar near the Cave of Pan at Caesarea Philippi"
  lies in ruins.
- p1728: "Pools of Bethesda in Jerusalem" were excavated.
- p1739: "The Pool of Siloam." Evidence shows that this pool was used
  in Jesus' day.